# After addOnSuccessListener() the app is redirected to other activity

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

In my app I have implemented image upload to firebase storage, after upload url of the image is stored in realtime database for future use. Everything is working perfectly except whenever the url of the image is stored in realtime database the app move towards the BottomNavigation. below is my code
**Adapter Class from which the app is redirected towards the pictureTakingActivity**

```
class PrintAdapter(val data:ArrayList<PrintModel>)  : RecyclerView.Adapter<PrintAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        var view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_row_home, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.name.setText(data.get(position).name)
        Picasso.get().load(data[position].image).into(holder.image)
        Log.d("TAG", "The image is: " + data[position].catName)
        var cat = data.get(position).catName

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            if (cat.equals("photo")){
                val intent  = Intent(it.context, PictureTakingActivity::class.java)
                it.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
      return  data.size
    }
    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        // Both of these can be used to find id
        var name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.printName)
        var image = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.circleImageView1)
    }
}
```

**PictureTakingActivity**

```
class PictureTakingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var uri: Uri
    lateinit var binding: ActivityPictureTakingBinding
    lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
    lateinit var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser
    lateinit var id: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityPictureTakingBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
        id = firebaseUser.uid


        binding.takePhoto.setOnClickListener {

            ImagePicker.with(this)
                .crop()
                .galleryMimeTypes(
                    mimeTypes = arrayOf(
                        "image/png",
                        "image/jpg",
                        "image/jpeg"
                    )
                )
                .cameraOnly()
                .compress(1024)
                .maxResultSize(1080, 1080)
                .start()


        }

        binding.uploadGallery.setOnClickListener {
            ImagePicker.with(this)
                .crop()
                .galleryMimeTypes(
                    mimeTypes = arrayOf(
                        "image/png",
                        "image/jpg",
                        "image/jpeg"
                    )
                )
                .galleryOnly()
                .compress(1024)
                .maxResultSize(1080, 1080)
                .start()
        }

        binding.ok.setOnClickListener {
            uploadImage()
        }
        binding.notOk.setOnClickListener {
            ImagePicker.with(this)
                .crop()
                .galleryMimeTypes(
                    mimeTypes = arrayOf(
                        "image/png",
                        "image/jpg",
                        "image/jpeg"
                    )
                )
                .compress(1024)
                .maxResultSize(1080, 1080)
                .start()
        }



    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //Image Uri will not be null for RESULT_OK
        uri = data?.data!!
        binding.userImage.setImageURI(uri)

        binding.takePhoto.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.uploadGallery.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        binding.ok.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.notOk.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        Log.d("TAG", "The uri inside is: $" )
    } else if (resultCode == ImagePicker.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ImagePicker.getError(data), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Task Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    }

    private fun uploadImage(){
        val progressBar = ProgressDialog(this)
        progressBar.setMessage("Uploading file...")
        progressBar.setCancelable(false)
        progressBar.show()

        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss", Locale.getDefault())
        val now = Date()
        val fileName = formatter.format(now)

        val storageRefrence = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(id).child("images/$fileName")
        storageRefrence.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener {
            progressBar.dismiss()
            storageRefrence.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {

                databaseReference.child("Users").child(id).child("image").setValue(it.toString()).addOnSuccessListener { // After this line is executed app redirect towards MainActivity
                   
              Toast.makeText(this, "File uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }

        }.addOnFailureListener{
            progressBar.dismiss()
        }
}
}
```

**BottomNavigationActivity**

```
class BottomNavigationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding:ActivityBottomNavigationBinding
    private val fragment1: Fragment = HomeFragment()
    private val fragment2: Fragment = DocumentsFragment()
    private val fragment3: Fragment = OrdersFragment()
    private val fragment4: Fragment = ProfileFragment()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityBottomNavigationBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)




        replaceFrameLayout(fragment1)

        binding.bottomNavigation.setOnItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.home -> replaceFrameLayout(fragment1)
                R.id.documents -> replaceFrameLayout(fragment2)
                R.id.orders -> replaceFrameLayout(fragment3)
                R.id.profile -> replaceFrameLayout(fragment4)

                else ->{

                }
            }
            true
        }

    }

    private fun replaceFrameLayout(fragment: Fragment){
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flFragment, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

    }
```

I am new in Kotlin so please pardon if this is a simple issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you are launching activity for result, after executing onActivityResult redirecting back is expected

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Are you sure the app **redirects**, and doesn't actually crash and thus restart on the main activity. If the latter is happening, you should be able to find an exception and stack trace in the logcat output which would explain the cause.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have checked the logcat and no error is being display.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the BottomNaviationActivity code, this is where the app is redirected.

Comment: It sounds like your app is crashing and relaunching the default activity (probably `MainActivity`) when the crash happens. Check your logcat right after the crash happens - if you see a Stacktrace, please paste it here and we might be able to help